how to get startup manager on 24.10
i accidently removed startup manager app from my laptop, I would like to reinstall it but when i try to sudo apt install gnome-startup-applications,it shows
Package gnome-startup-applications is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source Error: Package 'gnome-startup-applications' has no installation candidate

I'd check your machine sources (either directly, and/or ensuring you note the output of sudo apt update ensuring there are no missing lines, no warnings/errors etc) as I see the package available, ie. gnome-startup-applications | 46.0-8ubuntu1   | oracular       | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x  ... FYI:  This isn't a new install where you've not actually had your machine look for what's available online yet is it?  (ie. have never actually run apt update)

iam a bit new to ubuntu so , i really dont get what your asking me to do

The package is available; the detail I posted is from a CLI enquiry as to availability of the package & copy/pasted that output into prior comment. A used system should know about what packages are available & see the package I provided details of in prior comment. To ensure your systems knows what is available the sudo apt update command is run; it updates software lists of what is available on your machine (doesn't change packages; apt install or apt upgrade will do that).  I'm suggesting you run that command & ensure there are no warnings/errors shown in the output etc.

no error , it shows everything is up to date

Then you have a problem with your sources; the output was likely missing a line & you didn't notice it... so explore your sources & ensure everything is there (sources are found in the /etc/apt/sources.list file, PLUS contents of files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory). Its those files that sudo apt update reads to find what software is available; if that was done it would detect the package I pasted details from.. Other things to check are what mirror was shown in apt update file; is it a valid mirror? up-to-date etc.. You explore the output of apt update for clues.

theres no error anywhere, is there a way i can get the .deb of startup applications app

Re-read what I said; I said "ensuring there are no missing lines, no warnings/errors etc" ... where missing lines are actually a problem that you action... As a newbie you won't be familiar with what that output should look like; but its there for a reason; warnings & missing detail in the report are what you look for as well as the more obvious errors. That output also shows what mirror/source you're using, and that detail allows you to check https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors etc to look for problems, alternatives etc, so you scan for more than just errors.

nvm , i decided to just get ubuntu tweaks app
